# ExtJS combo load and disable

Tags: forms, combobox, extjs, load

I summarize the issue like this.

I use a form to edit user information which is loaded from the DB (I get these values through a JSONStore)

I want to enable/disable a combo depending on the loaded value of another combo.

Example: disable combo2 if the loaded value into combo1 = 0

- if I load combo1 = 1, combo2 = 12 :
  Everything fine
- if I load combo1 = 0, combo2 = 15 : Disable combo2

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A listener like this should do the job:

```
formEditUser.getForm().on('actioncomplete',function(form,action) {
  if(combo1.getValue() == 0) {
    combo2.disable();
  } else if (combo1.getValue() == 1) {
    combo2.enable();
  }
})
```

Comment: The change event might not fire without interactive change.

Comment: I see now what you mean, although it's not entirely clear what OP means by 'value is loaded into combo'. If he means value loaded into JsonStore then use JsonStore's `load` event to do this.

Comment: The change event does not seem to work. The data is loaded into the form using the following command (formEditUser is a GridPanel, and it is into an ExtJS window):  
   
formEditUser.getForm().load({ 
        url: 'gen/jsonUser.php',
        params:{IDUser:IDUser},
        waitMsg: 'Loading...'
    });

After this, I need to read the data loaded into combo1. In case the value is 0, then combo2 should be reset (clearValue()) and disabled.

Comment: In this case fetch form's basicForm using `formEditUser.getForm()` and use it's `actioncomplete` listener. I'll update the code above in a moment.

Comment: I was working on a similar code... but it does not seem to work. If I try something like this: 
formEditUser.getForm().on('actioncomplete',function(form,action) {
var comboFaculties = Ext.getCmp('comboFacultiesPrereg'); 
alert(comboFaculties.getId());
alert(comboFaculties.getValue());
}

and you know what happens? I can see the ID of the element but value gives an empty Alert. I tried delay:1000 but that does not help. I guess the problem is that when the event actioncomplete is fired, the combo has not yet its value.

Comment: Strange.. In that case you might want to add `success` handler to your load command and see what happens: `formEditUser.getForm().load({ url: '', success: function(form,action) {}, ...)`

Comment: BTW: In this function you can examine `action.result` to get the values straight from the server response, instead of fetching them from form fields.

Comment: Probably I was writing something wrong in my tests and some of the above mentioned solutions may work anyway. Anyway now it works and I decided to implement it looking at action.result.data, that is skipping to load data into the form and go to read the value from there. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

working code segment:

```
enter code here
                                           {xtype: 'fieldset',
                                            items: [{xtype: 'combo',
                                                     hiddenName: 'category[line]',
                                                     fieldLabel: 'Category',
                                                     store: categories,
                                                     emptyText: 'Select',
                                                     triggerAction: 'all',
                                                     mode: 'local',
                                                     displayField: 'category_name',
                                                     valueField: 'id',
                                                     anchor: '50%',
                                                     listeners:{
                                                        select:{fn:function(thisCombo, value) {
                                                            var combo = Ext.getCmp('combo-subcats');      
                                                                combo.enable();
                                                                //combo.clearValue();
                /* category is part of the json data inside the subcat. So the first select choose the category - then filter out only that bit and populate the subcat combo. Make sense?                   */                         combo.store.filter('category', values.data['category']);
                                                            }}
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {xtype: 'combo',
                                                     hiddenName: 'subcats[line]',
                                                     disabled: true,
                                                     id: 'combo-subcats',
                                                     fieldLabel: 'Sub Cat',
                                                     store: getSubcatsStore(),
                                                     emptyText: 'Select',
                                                     triggerAction: 'all',
                                                     mode: 'local',
                                                     displayField: 'name',
                                                     valueField: 'id',

                                                     anchor: '50%',
                                                     lastQuery: '' //<-- this is what makes it work.
                                                    },
```